# Why my Windows service only establishes connection with database when SQL Server Service runs under Local System account?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, kerberos, windows-authentication, spn

My windows service is using integrated authentication and running under Local System account and got the below exception.

> The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

The SQL Server Service is running under domain admin user e.g. "domain\administrator". If I change the SQL Server Service to run under Local System account then it fixes the above error.

Can anyone explain why it's happening like this? We have an InstallShield wizard which installs our application on client side i don't know how we can handle this behavior through the wizard. Also changing the user for SQL Server Service is not realistic as well because the client may not allow it.

> Note: Once when my windows service works fine and I revert the SQL Server run under the admin account my service runs fine. I guess there are some permissions are set to the local system account.

Before it, I ran the Kerberos which generated the following script to run and fixed the issue. After this it was not required to change the user for SQL Server Service.

> SetSPN -d "MSSQLSvc/FQDN" "domain\machine$"
>
> SetSPN -s "MSSQLSvc/FQDN" "domain\administrator"

Please explain why it's happening and what is the best way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running under the Local System account, [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) registers an [spn](/questions/tagged/spn) for every service it controls automatcially up to [active-directory](/questions/tagged/active-directory), and attempts to unregister them when the service shuts down.  The Local System account has the ability to communicate over the network as the computer account and thus can indicate to Active Directory as to when to make changes about itself and the SPN SQL Service wants to register.   When you change the SQL Server account over to an AD domain user account, the Local System account immediately loses it's ability to control this; therefore you must manually delete the existing SPNs previously registered for that SQL service by Local System *before* registering new SPNs. You should now notice why its nice that the SQL server script helpfully calls for a deletion of the old SPN followed by the registration of a new one in order to prevent issues.  When this isn't done properly - you'll get an authentication error when the kerberos clients obtain a ticket for the old invalid SPN - because it was never deleted and any Kerberos-aware service will always reject a ticket for a wrong SPN.  After you make SPN changes, always be sure to restart the SQL Server service and right after that if you’re testing with a user have that user log out and log back in.  This answers your main question here.

Please see this Microsoft document for further reading on the subject: [Register a Service Principal Name for Kerberos Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections).  There's also a very good youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC77XLfCsUex0Rvt4M22xYig) on this exact problem, that's where I learned about it and how to resolve it.   Ignore "SSRS" in the title, I've watched the entirety and the guidance applies to any and all services by SQL which have SPNs.

You had a secondary question at the very end of your question regarding what is the best way to handle the situation.  If you're talking about solving it programmatically that would be very difficult to answer as all environments are different in some way and you will come across SQL instances running in all sorts of different security contexts.  In an online forum like this you would probably get different answers from different people.  If this were your only question, I think it would get closed by the moderators for "being primarily opinion-based" and likely to attract spam answers.  I would suggest you incorporate some kind of guidance about the problem in some form of a Readme file that you should package with the InstallShield wizard.

Side note:  I think you should add the [kerberos](/questions/tagged/kerberos) tag to this question - as SPNs are relevant to Kerberos only - and not to any other authentication protocol.